# Changing the number format in google charts graphs of the Tooltip Data and also Y Axis

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization, tooltip, number-formatting

I need to add a comma after every thousand in my tooltip data (Y axis) and also in my Y axis. How do I go about changing the number format? I tried adding it in my codes but seems like it is not working. My vAxis and hAxis title display is also not working.

```
var options = {
  title:'<?php echo $row["$graph_title"];?>',
  height: 'auto',
  width : 'auto',
  tooltip : {trigger: 'selection'},
  is3D: true,
  vAxis: {title: '<?php echo $row1["$y_axis"]; ?>'},
  hAxis: {title: '<?php echo $row1["$x_axis"]; ?>'},
  bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
  vAxis: {format:'decimal'}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd go ahead with a `numberFormat`.
[The docmentation describes it](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter)  as

> Describes how numeric columns should be formatted. Formatting options include specifying a prefix symbol (such as a dollar sign) or the punctuation to use as a thousands marker.

```
var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ','
});
numberFormat.format(data, COLUMNNUMBER);
```

Comment: What if I want to do it for tooltip

Comment: The answer does exactly that.

Comment: do you have an example?